# How should I fix my infinite while loop that takes in 3 conditions? Also stylistic questions for novice

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, iteration, infinite-loop

writing code to test the Hailstone Sequence, also called Collatz conjecture. Code will print out the number of iterations of the Hailstone sequence.

```
def main():

start_num = eval (input ("Enter starting number of the range: "))
end_num = eval (input ("Enter ending number of the range: "))
```

The main problem is that my code returns an infinite loop. I want to check all of these conditions in one statement

```
while (start_num > 0 and end_num > 0 and end_num > start_num):
  cycle_length = 0
  max_length = 0
  max_number = 0
```

my code seems inefficient, there is probably a better way to approach the problem

```
for i in range(start_num, (end_num + 1)):
  cycle_length = 0
  while (i != 1):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
      i = i // 2
      cycle_length += 1
      if (i % 2 == 1):
        i = ((3 * i) + 1)
        cycle_length += 1
print (cycle_length)
```

I just started coding, and I always know that there is a more efficient way to approach these problems. Any suggestions on methodology, problem solving, or stylistic advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in order for you loop to reach its conclusion one of the conditions must become false at some point. So one of the values must equal 0 or less, or the last condition must become true with end_num being less than start_num

Comment: if this is an array the size will not change on its own

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a language tag, so that it can properly be categorized for search results. It also helps to get the question in front of people who can answer it, getting you help more quickly. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveHulse I think that i will become 1 after some number of iterations. The line 'while (i != 1):' is supposed to ensure that we exit the loop at the end condition of the sequence.

Comment: it doesn't become 1 if there is an infinite loop.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem

Comment: Well what is a good method for debugging code? My professor said to code iteratively, and at each iteration I should have working code. So that it is easy to know where the error lies.

Comment: I believe that the error is in trying to solve this problem on a modern personal computer.

Comment: do you know of any numbers that work? I have checked your code and it looks correct

Comment: binary numbers all work

Comment: I had never heard of this term before. So I know that there are seemingly infinite numbers that can be evaluated by this function. However, we define a range of values to check: 'for i in range(start_num, (end_num + 1)):' and print out the number of steps that the sequence had to take. 'print(cycle_length)'

Comment: I'm sorry I doubted you. I will write some code in java and let's see if you can translate it. The languages are very similar.

Comment: I am running Python 3.4.1 through my windows command prompt by typing python file.py But command prompt evaluates my function as infinite. I don't know the code jargon to describe infinitely looping code.

Comment: Don't use eval of user input.  Use ast.literar_eval or a specific class -- in this case `int`.  It is too easy to get in a bad habit and use it when it creates a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer in java. I assume that we will not start with 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int counter =0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Give us a number to start with:");
            int start = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Give us a number to end with:");
            int end = sc.nextInt();
            if (end > start) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= end - start; i++) {
                    counter = 0;
                    int num = start + i;
                    int temp = num;
                    while(temp != 1) {
                        if ( temp % 2 == 0 ) {
                            temp = temp / 2;
                        } else {
                            temp = 3* temp +1;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(num + " takes " + counter + "iterations.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your numbers do not make sense.");
            }

        }
```

Here's an answer in python in case you're staying up late trying to solve this problem. :P Have a good night.

```
start_num = 1
end_num = 10
for i in range(start_num, (end_num + 1)):
    cycle_length=0
    num = i
    while (num != 1):
        if (num % 2 == 0):
             num = num // 2
             cycle_length+=1
        else:
             num = ((3 * num) + 1)
             cycle_length+=1
    print(cycle_length)
```

Comment: 1 takes 0iterations.
2 takes 1iterations.
3 takes 7iterations.
4 takes 2iterations.
5 takes 5iterations.
6 takes 8iterations.
7 takes 16iterations.
8 takes 3iterations.
9 takes 19iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dave! I'll try to translate this code to make my python code run. Thanks for the insight as well.

Comment: I added a solution in python as well. I have never used python so that was fun.